# Multiple web forms for a single Podio App

Tags: podio

Is there any way to add multiple web forms (with different fields selected) for a single App in Podio.

**Example**

Form1:

[image]

Form 2:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create multiple webforms for same app, but only from Podio API and not from Podio UI.
Here is example of creating simplest webform from API:

```
  webform_config = { 'settings' => { 'captcha' => true,
                                     'text' => {'heading' => 'heading',
                                                'description' => 'description',
                                                'submit' => 'submit',
                                                'success' => 'thank you!'},
                                     'theme' => 'flat'},
                     'domains' => [],
                     'fields' => [{'field_id' => <field external id>}],
                     'attachments' => true}
  form = Podio::Form.create(<app id>, webform_config)
```

Comment: Thank you :) But it would be better if there is a way to do this from the UI, so that anyone with no knowledge of APIs can work with this.

Answer (score 0):

we had the same problem and had built an in-house solution to this problem. After many Podio partners asked us to open it up we made a Podio extension out of it.

Feel free and give our dynamic podio form extension a try at https://momentumtools.io/podio-forms .

Other than multiple forms per app we also support conditional fields, editable items, data validation, wizards, etc :).

Hope you like it :)!